# Connect to external database cluster from kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

Is there option to connect to external database cluster from POD? I need to connect to elastic search, zookeeeper, Kafka and couchbase, each of them has its own cluster. Per my understanding [the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors), I can define multi external IPs, but I cannot find how will k8s behave if one of them is down. I am working with pure k8s 1.6 now, and we will migrate to 1.7 soon. Information about OpenShift 3.7 will be also welcome because I cannot find anything specific in [its documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/dev_guide/integrating_external_services.html).

Answer (score 3):

The k8s doc on your link has more info on exposing services running on k8s but not externally

You generally want to expose your service using a DNS entry and manage the HA for that service separately.

For example you can a single DNS entry `mykafka.mydomain.com` and then assign IP addresses to that entry:

```
kafka1 ip
kafka2 ip
kafka3 ip
```

You can see that approach on the Openshift docs in the `USING AN EXTERNAL DOMAIN NAME` section. Yes, its not clear from the docs whether k8s/openshift does a round robin on the multiple IPs for an external service and if automatically fails over.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You added one more term to search - "round robin", but I still cannot find it :-(